# How to change background color of checkbox after checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am creating a checkboxes from the ts file in angular for seat selection but the background color of checkbox is not changing after checking the checkboxes.

**My ts file function:**

```
generateSeats(): void {
    const seats = document.querySelector('.all-seats');
    if (!seats) return;
    for (let i = 0; i \<= 59; i++) 
    const randint = Math.floor(Math.random() \* 2);
        const booked = randint === 1 ? 'booked' : '';
        seats.insertAdjacentHTML(
          'beforeend',
          `<input type="checkbox" name="tickets" id="s${i + 2}"/>         
          <label for="s${i + 2}" class="seat ${booked} grid"></label>`
        );
    }
}
```

**My html snippet:**

```
<div class="all-seats" >
  <input type="checkbox" name="tickets" id="s1" />

  <label for="s1" class="seat booked size"></label>
</div>
```

**One of my css attempts:**

```
.all-seats input:checked + label {

    background-color: rgb(28, 185, 120) !important;
    outline: none;

}
```

Please help me change the background color of checkbox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style a checkbox using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new CSS accent-color property to change the background colour of the checkbox:

```
.all-seats input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  accent-color: rgb(28, 185, 120) !important;
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: This works. Downvotes should require an explanation.